# Building MicroSIP 3.19.18: "PJRPID_ACTIVITY_ON_THE_PHONE" not defined

Tags: visual-c++

I am trying to build a custom modified version of the
[MicroSIP softphone](https://www.microsip.org/).

Before any modifications, I can't build the version 3.19.18 using VisualStudio 2017.

I am able to compile successfully the previous minor version: 3.18.5

The error is:

```
1>c:\users\xxxxxxxxx\microsip\maindlg.cpp(1038): error C2065: 'PJRPID_ACTIVITY_ON_THE_PHONE': undeclared identifier
```

If I look at the code that uses that identifier I come across this, that is new in 3.19:

```
                case PJSUA_BUDDY_STATUS_ONLINE:
                if (buddy_info.rpid.activity == PJRPID_ACTIVITY_ON_THE_PHONE) {
                    image = MSIP_CONTACT_ICON_ON_THE_PHONE;
                    if (PjToStr(&buddy_info.status_text).Left(4) == _T("Ring")) {
                        ringing = true;
```

If I look at the type of "buddy_info.rpid.activity" it's of type "pjrpid_activity" That is defined in "rpid.h" from the SIP library "pjsip" :

```
typedef enum pjrpid_activity
{
/** Activity is unknown. The activity would then be conceived
 *  in the "note" field.
 */
PJRPID_ACTIVITY_UNKNOWN,

/** The person is away */
PJRPID_ACTIVITY_AWAY,

/** The person is busy */
PJRPID_ACTIVITY_BUSY

} pjrpid_activity;
```

No 'PJRPID_ACTIVITY_ON_THE_PHONE' defined here. And that string can't be found anywhere else on that project.

This enum is part of the Open Source project [pjsip](https://www.pjsip.org/) which is currently on version 2.9.

I tried to look back into earlier versions to find out if that enum evolved and had the correct elements. No luck.

It looks like they are using a modified version of the pjsip library, but I can't find a link, a mention or anything that would help me to find out what is that missing dependency.

More than that, MicroSIP.org will charge you $95 to obtain a customized version including "source code and assistance with compilation if needed".

Of course it is needed if they keep secret the dependencies.

Anyway, MicroSIP is statically linked to the unknown pjsip library variant.
 Microsip and PJSIP are both licensed under the GPLv2.

My question is: How to find out my missing dependency?

Are they required to disclose that information?

Does anyone know about a fork of pjsip that would be the one I am looking for?

Better, Has anyone been able to somehow compile MicroSIP, ver >= 3.19.0?

Comment: Hi, did you manage to find out a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, I contacted MicroSip.org and they kindly sent to me the modified pjsip file.
now I can compile without any issue

Comment: Sorry for digging up an old thread...Can you expand on your compile environment and dependencies?  We're getting ready to do some changes to microSIP and I want to start with a known-working build environment.

Comment: @surfrock66 I don't have access to the build environment anymore. IIRC, except for the issues with the missing PJSIP modification in the pjproject-2.9 project, I had no problem at all compiling the project with VS2017

Comment: Sorry to bug you again; the source didn't come with a .sln file so our visual studio isn't importing the project.  Did you have a .sln file?  I usually compile for linux so I'm not very familiar with visual studio.

Comment: @surfrock66 Have a look at that GitHub: 
https://github.com/Blup1980/microsip_42
The project should have an .sln file.
I am compiling branch "joystick_3.19.27"
Thanks to Open source, have a look and adapt it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To build any distribution of Microsip, you should build [pjsip](https://www.pjsip.org/) first. Therefore you should set some source and library paths for the Microsip project. Then you can build cleanly. It may be that some library is missing like opus, etc... and you may need to find the current version of these and build them beforehand as well.

Answer (score 0):

I came to see that you must be having different platform toolset for MicroSIP and PjProject. Try to build it from starting using the same build tool and platform toolset for the both of your project, it will automatically clear several issues.